# Updates column values using expressions

Tags: ssis

I have a data flow pipeline that takes data from a file and puts it into a table. I added a derived column from a variable (that has the file name) to add the file name to the pipeline. The derived column component throws the error "Updates column values using expressions" when run. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the text "Updates column values using expressions" is an error?  it looks to be the default tooltip for a Derived Column component.  How are you determining the "Error" you are getting?

Comment: You're right, it's a truncation error. I needed to cast the variable to the right type of string. Please add this as an answer so I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Updates column values using expressions" is the tooltip for the component where your package is failing.  You need to look at the Progress tab during or Execution Results tab after a run to determine what your actual error is.